# User login password error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create login system with access level but i the bellow code always shows please enter you password. please help me where i am wrong.

```
session_start();

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['password'];
    if($username){
        if($password){
        require('conn/iclude.php');
        $password=sha1($password);
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where name='$username'");
        $numrow=mysql_num_rows($query);
            if($numrow==1){
                $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                $dbid=$row['id'];
                $dbuser=$row['name'];
                $dbpass=$row['pass'];
                $role=$row['role'];
                if($password==$dbpass) {
                    $_SESSION['username']=$dbuser;
                    $_SESSION['useridid']=$dbid;
                    if($role == 1){
                    header('Location:admin.php');
                    }elseif ($role==2) {
                    header('Location:1/neasp.php');
                    }elseif ($role==3) {
                    header('Location:2/index.php');
                    }elseif ($role==4) {
                    header('Location:3/index.php');
                    }elseif ($role==5) {
                    header('Location:4/index.php');
                    } 
                }else{}
            }else{
                echo"Hello World";
                }
        }else{echo "You must enter your password";}

    }else {echo "You must enter your name";}
}
```

thanks below is html form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $mypassword=$_POST['password'];
     ^^^^^^^^^^^  **MY** password

    if($password){
        ^^----no **MY**
```

If your system was properly configured for debugging, e.g. `display_errors` and `error_reporting` turned on, you'd have gotten warnings about using undefined variables. A development/test system should **NEVER* have these settings off in the first place.

You are also vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Thanks but its stacked in login page nothing happens even my user and password is correct please help

Comment: Why should it work? Later on you have `$password = sha1($password)`, without ever having DEFINED that variable.As I hinted... you REALLY need to turn on display_errors/error_reporting.